# Is there an option to update or draw last candle on a chart based on real-time trading?

Tags: highcharts

I need to stream last trade and update last candle according to the information from last trade that includes price, bid, ask.  Candle chart accepts OHLC format data, but I need to redraw this candle using  Last quote information(price, bid, ask)
I have read all the documentation regarding work with data and live data in highcharts, but still could not figure out how to stream last trade on stock chart.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `series.addPoint` method:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint({
  x: 3,
  open: 1,
  high: 3,
  low: 6,
  close: 7,
  name: "Point1"
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4978/

**API Reference:**  https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

---

Or `point.update` to change the last point data:

```
var series = chart.series[0];

series.points[series.points.length - 1].update({
  x: 2,
  open: 2,
  high: 4,
  low: 5,
  close: 6,
  name: "Point1",
  color: "#FF00FF"
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4979/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know about this API methods, but they accept OHLC data, while I have to use tick-by-tick data (bid, ask, price, dt). I wondered if there's any higcharts API that could help me to convert this data?

Comment: Hi @Ekaterina , There is no such method in the API. You need to convert data by yourself.